# Google Authentication/Gapi: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, google-api-js-client

*Good day to everyone!*

I'm creating a web app using **Angular.js 1.5**, **Google Authentication (gapi)** and **UI router**.

My main goal is to initialize **GoogleUser** at the first place, using **resolve method** from the main abstract state:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      url:'/',
      templateUrl: 'layout/app-view.html',
      resolve: {
        googleAuth: function (User:UserService) {
          return User.initCurrent();
        }
      }
    });
```

which at that point works pretty well - it injects **UserService**, and call its **initCurrent()** method, that returns a **promise** which will be fullfiled once current user will be initialized. Here is **UserService concise code**:

```
class UserService implements UserInterface {
  public current:GoogleUser;
  private _GoogleAuth:GoogleAuthService;
  private _AppConstants;

  constructor(GoogleAuth:GoogleAuthService) {
    'ngInject';
    this._GoogleAuth = GoogleAuth;
  }

  initCurrent():ng.IPromise<GoogleUser> {
    return this._GoogleAuth.getCurrentUser().then((current) => {
      this.current = current;
      return this.current;
    })
  }
}
```

In its turn **initCurrent()** receive a promise from **getCurrentUser()** that will be fulfilled once the **gapi** will be loaded and **GoogleAuth** instance will be initialized. For that I've created a **GoogleAuthService**:

```
class GoogleAuthService implements GoogleAuthServiceInterface {
  public googleAuth;
  private _AppConstants;
  private deferGoogleAuthInit:ng.IDeferred<any>;

  constructor(AppConstants, $log, $q:ng.IQService) {
    'ngInject';
    this._AppConstants = AppConstants;
    this.deferGoogleAuthInit = $q.defer();
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: AppConstants.googleClientId,
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
      }).then((googleAuth) => {
        this.googleAuth = googleAuth;
        this.deferGoogleAuthInit.resolve('GoogleAuth Initialized');
      })
    });
  }
  getCurrentUser() {
    return this.deferGoogleAuthInit
      .promise.then(() => {
        return this.googleAuth.currentUser.get()
      })
  }
}
```

**The problem:** When I'm not using resolve method to initialize user, and do all the same via console: getting UserService instance, initCurrentUser and etc. everything works fine: signIn/signOut, getting current User and etc. 
But when I initialize current User inside resolve method, attempt to signOut  causes the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postMessage' of null

But at the same time all services are injecting properly and I'm receiving a proper user instance, although I cannot reSignIn it. What would you suggest?

Comment: Did you ever solve it?

Comment: Nope. Eventually I decided not to use gapi library, and developed my own custom function that deals with token retrieving/refreshing and it works just fine. Also I've opened the  [github issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/238) related to the problem, I've described.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem on react app. I was able to solve by changing CORS policy as below:

```
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin-allow-popups
```

Savior reference -

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/796#issuecomment-1118136612

(found from - [Why Google-Auth(Google Identity) Blank popup in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371354/why-google-authgoogle-identity-blank-popup-in-django))