# Google Oauth2: Refreshing id_token on the client side

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm developing an angularjs web app.

To access server side api, I need to add an *id_token* header and
I receive an id_token, by using `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth endpoint`.

The crux of the matter is this - the *id_token* has an *expiration date*. Before accessing server API, I need to make sure the *id_token* is not expired yet, but if it is, the obvious choice would be to *refresh it*.

Is there any way I can *refresh the id_token*?

I know I could change access_type to *offline*, and receive a *refresh_token*, but it does seem pretty weird to ask for an *offline access*, when basically in my case user interacts with the server only at the moment when he actually using the web app online.

Comment: I don't think you need to refresh the id token. Your app can manage its own session once you have the claims you need from the id token. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686484/what-is-intent-of-id-token-expiry-time-in-openid-connect

Answer (score 1):

Forget all about refresh tokens and offline access. This method is only applicable for server and desktop apps. To have a refresh token present in the browser would be a massive security hole.

If you read the docs for the Google JS OAuth library, you'll see that it's easy to get a new access token once the current one expires. See gapi.auth.authorize() and note the comment for immediate=true. NB this method is deprecated, although it works. Absolutely everything you need to   is at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not using gapi library, because of the problem I've described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392912/google-authentication-gapi-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-postmessag  and also I've opened an issue https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/238

Comment: In case it helps, I've wrapped gapi in an Angular 1 service here https://github.com/pinoyyid/ngDrive/blob/master/src/oauth_s.ts

Answer (score 0):

> When the id_token expires, the client requests new tokens from the
>   server, so that the user does not need to authorise again.

From  [IMPLEMENTING A SILENT TOKEN RENEW IN ANGULAR FOR THE OPENID CONNECT IMPLICIT FLOW](https://damienbod.com/2017/06/02/implementing-a-silent-token-renew-in-angular-for-the-openid-connect-implicit-flow/)