# Why Google-Auth(Google Identity) Blank popup in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, google-authentication, google-identity

My Google Auth is Stuck in the popup auth flow. The one-tap authentication works just fine but not the button`<div id="g_id_signin"></div>`. I click on it, the popup opens but it remains there blank with no progress.

```
<script>
   function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
     console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
     ...
    }
   window.onload = function () {
     google.accounts.id.initialize({
       client_id: "531144-------",
       callback: handleCredentialResponse
     });
     google.accounts.id.renderButton(
       document.getElementById("g_id_signin"),
       { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
     );
     google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
   }
</script>
<div id="g_id_signin"></div>
```

I have all the domains, localhost added in Authorized redirect URIs and Redirects. But I still can't get the popup to populate and complete the authentication flow.
Any help is appreciated.

At this point the error I am getting in FIREFOX:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.opener is null
> li https://ssl.gstatic.com/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en.i....O/am=wg/d=1/rs=AF0...w/m=credential_page_library:291
> mi https://ssl.gstatic.com/_/gsi/_/js/k=gsi.gsi.en.i.....O/am=wg/d=1/rs=AF0...w/m=credential_page_library:29

And in CHROME:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'postMessage')
> at li (m=credential_page_library:291:151)

Answer (score 3):

You have to set `SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY` to `"same-origin-allow-popups"` in settings.py.

Reference: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/796#issuecomment-1118136612

Comment: I recently faced this problem as well when upgrading our Django from 3.2 to 4.2 and setting `SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY` to `same-origin-allow-popups` didn't help, but setting it to `unsafe-none` solved the issue.